# Get position in list of the first element with a certain property

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider a toy list

```
l = {x[2],x[32],x[43],x[56],x[72]};
```

I would like to find the position of the first element within this list, for which `x[y]` is such that `y>N` where `N` is a positive integer that I will specify. In case if `N` is bigger than any label of any `x[y]`, then the result should be zero. So for example:

```
getPos[l,35]
```

> `3`

```
getPos[l,60]
```

> `5`

```
getPos[l,80]
```

> `0`

How can I do that in an efficient manner?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question but `FirstPosition`?

Comment: Beware of things like `x[n_] := 3; l = {x[2],x[32],x[43],x[56],x[72]};`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For default you can use third arg as in

```
p[n_] := First@FirstPosition[l, x[k_] /; k >= n, {0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a comment by [unlikely](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/16267/unlikely) here is the solution:

```
getPos[l_List,myN_Integer]:=FirstPosition[l,x[qq_Integer] /; qq > myN,{0}][[1]]
```

Comment: Better to use `n` than `N`.

Comment: Fixed it to something that starts with a lower case letter.